# Simulating clicks on items using Robolectric

Tags: java, android, onclicklistener, achartengine, robolectric

I figured this type of question would have already been asked but I can't seem to find an answer that does what I need. I have an ExpandableListView and the last child in each group is clickable. I need to simulate a click on that particular item, which is the third child. I've tried variations of .performClick and .dispatchTouchEvent but I haven't gotten anything to work right. Basically what I need is call the group's onChildClick listener and make sure that the item selected is that last one. Any ideas? Let me know if I can add any information.

Note: I'm using a code coverage calculator so that is how I know that the listener isn't being called. I'm using robolectric to run unit tests.

Also, I need to do something similar for a graphicalView with aChartEngine where it will simulate a click on a certain region of a doughnut chart. Any insight on this will be appreciated as well.

Answer (score 1):

Looks [similar to another q](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21552642/140278). Try the helper method performItemClick:

```
Robolectric.shadowOf(expandableListView).performItemClick(position);
```

Answer (score 1):

Since Robolectric 3.0 the API changed. You need now to call this to simulate the click on the item:

```
...    
Shadows.shadowOf(yourListInstance).performItemClick( index );
...
```